# sorting for array object needed in JavaScript using default .sort()

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array :

```
var array = [
{ID : 1,
Name : one,
data : {more info here}
},
{ID : 2,
Name : two
},
{ID : 3,
Name : three,
data : {more info here}
},
{ID : 4,
Name : four
},
{ID : 5,
Name : five,
data : {more info here}
},]
```

Need to sort these array, where data is present will be top, then other.
Final sort result will be -

```
[{ID:1,name: one,data: {}},
{ID:3,name: three,data: {}},
{ID:5,name: five,data: {}},
{ID:2,name: two},
{ID:4,name: four}]
```

Comment: By " where data is present will be top, then other" do you actually mean that you want all those with `data` first, sorted in increasing `ID` order, then all those without `data` also sorted in  increasing `ID` order?

Comment: BTW: It would be better if you provided your input array in a randomized order. As it is, some of the answers rely on the array's input order to end up with the overall array order you have specified as your output. If all you care about is that all those with `data` should be before all those without `data` and you don't care what order they are in within those two groups, then providing randomized input might not matter. In other words, if the array result is OK if the `ID`s are in the order `[5,1,3,4,2]`, then this might not matter?

Comment: Note: I down voted because your question currently does not indicate if the resulting array should also be sorted by `ID` (i.e. your question implies that this may be the case, but is not clear). If you clarify that you either do, or do not, care about the order of `ID` within the have `data`/not have `data` subgroups, I will remove my down vote. If you do clarify this (one way or the other), please leave a comment with `@Makyen` in it so I am notified to come back and take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the delta of the boolen values of the properties.

```js
var array = [{ ID: 1, Name: 'one', data: {} }, { ID: 2, Name: 'two' }, { ID: 3, Name: 'three', data: {} }, { ID: 4, Name: 'four' }, { ID: 5, Name: 'five', data: {} }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return !a.data - !b.data;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another version with stress on the key could be the check for existence.

```js
var array = [{ ID: 1, Name: 'one', data: {} }, { ID: 2, Name: 'two' }, { ID: 3, Name: 'three', data: {} }, { ID: 4, Name: 'four' }, { ID: 5, Name: 'five', data: {} }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return ('data' in b) - ('data' in a);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It is unclear from the question if it is required, but this currently relies on the order of the input array to have the result end up matching the requested output array order. In other words,  you do not check the `ID` for sorting within the have `data` and not have `data` groups. In other words, you rely on the input array already being sorted by `ID` in order for your `data`/non-`data` groups to be sorted by `ID`.

Comment: you are right, the result is not stable with the given sort parameters. for a stable value, it is necessary to add another paramter for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question if the only thing that matters in the desired sort is the presence or absence of the `data` property. The desired "final sort result" shows the data sorted first by the presence or absence of `data`, but then in ascending order of `ID` within those groups.  It is possible that sorting by `ID` is merely an artifact of the starting array order and is not a required part of the question. On the other hand, it may be that sorting by both `data` and then `ID` are both required.

The other solutions either do not sort at all based on the `ID` ([Nina Scholz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39766354/3773011)), or sort by both `data` and `ID`, but do so erroneously depending on the input array ([Rajesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39766463/3773011)). Both rely on the order of the input array to provide the desired result array.

The following code will sort the array based first on the presence or absence of `data` and then by `ID` within those two sub groups.

Sorting the originally provided input array:

```js
var array = [{ ID: 1, Name: 'one', data: {} }, { ID: 2, Name: 'two' }, { ID: 3, Name: 'three', data: {} }, { ID: 4, Name: 'four' }, { ID: 5, Name: 'five', data: {} }];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.data && !b.data) {
    // a has data, b does not have data, a is first
    return -1;
  }
  if(!a.data && b.data) {
    // a does not have data, b does have data, b is first
    return 1;
  }
  // a and b either both have data, or both don't have data. Sort the smaller ID first.
  return a.ID - b.ID;
});
console.log(array)
```

Below is the same sort starting with an input array slightly modified from the one used in [Rajesh's updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39766463/3773011). The array from that answer has been modified to change `ID:4,` to `ID:41,`. With that modified input array, Rajesh's sort will produce erroneous results. This code will sort it correctly by both `data` and `ID`.

```js
var array=[{ID:1,Name:"one",data:{"more info here":"something"}},{ID:2,Name:"two"},{ID:30,Name:"Thirty",data:{"more info here":"something"}},{ID:41,Name:"four"},{ID:5,Name:"five",data:{"more info here":"something"}},{ID:40,Name:"fourty",data:{"more info here":"something"}},{ID:300,Name:"threeHundred",data:{"more info here":"something"}},{ID:20,Name:"twenty"},{ID:3e3,Name:"threeThousand",data:{"more info here":"something"}}];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.data && !b.data) {
    // a has data, b does not have data, a is first
    return -1;
  }
  if(!a.data && b.data) {
    // a does not have data, b does have data, b is first
    return 1;
  }
  // a and b either both have data, or both don't have data. Sort the smaller ID first.
  return a.ID - b.ID;
});
console.log(array)
```